# R Shiny: loop that generates as many outputs as the user chooses

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a loop that generates as many outputs as the user chooses.
for example, if the user chooses 10 models, 10 outputs of those 10 models will come out.

Note: I know that inputs cannot be used within the UI. I just use it as a reference to make it clearer to understand what I am trying to do.

Here is what I've tried:

```
shinyApp(ui= fluidPage(checkboxGroupInput('aa','model',c('a','b','c'), 'a'),
                       for(i in 1:length(input$aa)){
                         function(i){uiOutput(paste0('prob', i))}
                       }),
         server = function(input, output){
           for(i in input$aa){
             assign(paste('output$prob',i,sep = ''),renderUI({paste('model',i)}))
           }
                     })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `shiny`, `for` loops don't work well, it's better to use `lapply`. Below you find a solution with `lapply`, you could also take a look at [`insertUI`/`removeUI`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/insertUI.html)

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(checkboxGroupInput('aa','model',c('a','b','c'), 'a'),
                uiOutput("formulas")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$formulas <- renderUI({
    lapply(input$aa, function(model) {
      verbatimTextOutput(paste0("prob_", model))
    })
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$aa, {
    lapply(input$aa, function(model) {
      output[[paste0("prob_", model)]] <- renderPrint({paste0("model ", model)})
    })
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```